# Email notification on Windows 10 showing the logo path (url / src) how can I get rid of it (PHP, SwiftMailer)

Tags: php, outlook, windows-10, swiftmailer

I am using SwiftMailer to send emails to my site members, I designed a template for it and it is working and looking fine, the only problem is that when the message arrives on the user's Windows 10 computer the notification shows more that it should as in the image below, I don't want to show the path to my logo in the notification plus it doesn't look good, I want to have custom text. I tried adding text on the top with display: none (because i don't want this text to show up in the email itself) but that didn't help, any suggestions please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You `img` tag must include the `alt` attribute.